# Regular expression for Arabic, and English Numbers, with country code as well

Tags: javascript, regex

The problem am trying to solve is i want to **validate** phone number in both languages , **arabic** and **english** numbers.

I searched alot on the internet to find best solution for my case
but most was to validate each one separately.

I need regular expression to validate the following for example
in my forms some one enters valid phone number ....

> **962772211756**

and

> **٩٦٢٧٩٦٩٦٩٩٣٠**

I prefer with **js fiddle** example, because when i try any example
from [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) it just hard to confirm why its not working
without jsfiddle, i tried lot of them already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is sample to fix that problem

**Reference**
[Unicode lookup  here :)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm)

https://jsfiddle.net/shareefhiasat/ky375uep/

```
 var regex 
= /^[+]*[(]{0,1}[\u0030-\u0039\u0660-\u0669]{1,3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./\u0030-\u0039\u0660-\u0669]*$/g;
var regex1 
= /^[+]*[(]{0,1}[\u0030-\u0039\u0660-\u0669]{1,3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./\u0030-\u0039\u0660-\u0669]*$/g;

                // [\u0000-\u007F\u0660-\u0669]

                 var code1 = '٩٦٢';
                var phone1 = '٧٩٦٩٦٩٩٣';
                var number1 = code1 + phone1;
                var result1 = regex1.test(number1);

                alert(result1);

                var code = '962';
                var phone = '77221175';
                var number = code + phone;
                var result = regex.test(number);

                alert(result);
```